# Exponential integrability of a sum of approximations of disjoint intervals characteristic functions

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $I=[0,1]$ be the unit segment, and let $(I_n)_{1\leq n \leq N}$ be $N$ almost disjoint sub-intervals $I_n=[t_n-\delta_n,t_n+\delta_n]$ of $I$ (that is, their interior are disjoint). Let $\chi(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ (which plays the role as an approximation of $1_{[-1,1]}$).

> How can one prove that there exists $C, c>0$ (independent of $N$ and the $I_n$) such that for all $\lambda >0$ there holds $$\left|\left\{x\in I, \sum_{n=1}^N \chi (\frac{x-t_n}{\delta_n})>\lambda\right\}\right|\leq Ce^{-c\lambda}?$$

This results seems surprisingly difficult to prove. It looks like one should try do do some John-Nirenberg argument, but I did not succeed this way.

Maybe it is possible to regroup intervals of width $ (2K)^{-1} \leq \delta_n < K^{-1}$ where $K\in 2^{\mathbb{N}}$. Let us denote by $A_K$ this subset of intervals and $|A_K|$ its cardinal. Without loss of generality one can assume that $I = \cup I_n$. Write $1=\sum |I_n| = \sum_K c_K$ where $c_K = \sum_{n\in A_K} |I_n|$, so that $$|\{x\in I, \sum_{n=1}^N \chi (\frac{x-t_n}{\delta_n})>\lambda\}|\leq \sum_K |\{x\in I, \sum_{n\in A_K} \chi (\frac{x-t_n}{\delta_n})>\lambda c_K\}|.$$
In theory, it should be easier to handle the terms $n\in A_K$ because all intervals have comparable sizes. However, I am not able to prove the right estimate.

Does anyone know how to prove it? I am looking for a rather elementary approach, as this looks really elementary.

Comment: The inequality looks kinda weird. Are you sure you want the same $C$ twice rather than $C e^{-c \lambda}$?

Comment: @mathworker21 I modified it, you are right, possibly not the same C.

Comment: Have you tried exponential moment method? I.e. do Markov/Chebyshev on both sides of inequality exponentiated?

Comment: Yes I tried that but then one should be able to estimate the integral of products which looks even more difficult.

Comment: Are you sure it's more difficult? Do you know whether the method can work, i.e. whether the integral of products is bounded above by a constant?

Comment: I am not sure (maybe someone can prove the result by this method), but to me this is as difficult: you are taking product of numbers larger than 1 (exponential terms), this is why it is kot easier

Comment: I upvoted to counteract the seemingly unjustified downvote

Comment: I don't care about downvotes. Maybe it is because the question is not well motivated. I'll reformulate later. The crucial thing is that the constant is independent on the number of intervals, so in particular you can even take an infinite number of intervals!

Comment: It is fairly straightforward to check that your sum has BMO norm less than 20 or so and conclude by John-Nierenberg, but you requested no high tech, so let me think a bit more if there is a completely trivial way to see it.

Comment: @fedja you're right! Computing the BMO $L^1$ based norm seems to work (I was trying to compute the $L^2$ based ...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest argument I can currently come up with is the following:

Let $f_j$ be non-negative functions on $[0,1]$ with $\sum_j f_j\le 1$ (characteristic functions of disjoint intervals in your case) and let $\Phi_j$ be some even decreasing on $[0,+\infty)$  averaging kernels (Poisson kernels in your case). Let $F=\sum_j f_j*\Phi_j$. Let $E=\{x\in[0,1]:F(x)>\lambda\}$.

Then
$$
\lambda|E|\le \int F\chi_E=\sum_j\int (f_j*\Phi_j)\chi_E
=\sum_j\int (\chi_E*\Phi_j)f_j
\\
\le \int (M\chi_E)\sum_jf_j\le \int (M\chi_E)\chi_{[0,1]}\le C|E|(1+\log\tfrac1{|E|})
$$
and the desired conclusion follows. Here $M$ is the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function. Unfortunately, it is still a bit on the high tech side, though slightly less so than BMO and John-Nierenberg.

Comment: Nice. So, it is mainly the Vitali covering lemma, to "remove" the overlaps.

Comment: Thank you, this seems better!